# Length required to get equivalent password security based on available character set

Tags: combinatorics

I understand a password of length 12 is very secure if each character is independent of the others and it potentially mixes the 26 lowercase, 26 uppercase, 10 digits, and 32 typeable special characters. But what if a password can only contain 26 of those 94 characters? How much longer must that password be, in order to achieve similar uncrackability?

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $x$
$$26^x=(26+26+10+32)^{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps others: It looks like the rule of thumb is that the password needs to be almost 40% longer for a character set of 26 than if a full 94 character set were available.